# jquery fade in/out not work second time round, it fades back out immediately

Tags: jquery, fade

I have some text which says 'login/signup'.
when you click the text a box fades in below it with some log in options. then when you click outside that box it fades out again.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$("#menu").on("click","#login",function() {
//the following is to keep this part clickable.
    $(this).find('div, span, input, a').addClass('noclick');

    $('#signups').fadeIn(200, function() {
        $('html').on('click', function(event) {
            var target = $( event.target );
                if (target.is('.noclick')) {                        
                }
                else{
                    $('#signups').fadeOut(200);
                }
            });
        });
    });
});
```

no idea why it isnt working any help would be appreciated.

Also which jquery version should i put a link to at top of page? or does it not matter?

thanx

**edit**
still got problems.... please read comments from first answer if you wish to help. thankyou

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to handle bubbled click event once on the document. It means that you need in jQuery method [one](http://api.jquery.com/one/#one-events-selector-data-handler) with selector argument.
Replace your `$('html').on(...` with this:

```
$(document).one('click', ':not(.noclick)', function() {
    $('#signups').fadeOut(200);
});
```

I recommend you latest first or second jQuery version.

Comment: genius. thankyou. also worked just changing $('html').on(... to $('html').one(... but your way uses less code so better :) thankyou

Comment: oh actually your way doesnt work... it seems it still fades even though i click a 'noclick' classed element... any ideas?

Comment: and even if we did get it to work.... if i click the 'noclick' zone that will then stop the clicks from working and i wont be able to fade out at all.....

Comment: perhaps a function separate to the fadein of the box with an if statement. so if(box is visible) { $(document).on('click' function(){ if($(target).is('.noclick'){do nothing} else {fade box out}... but how would i go about asking if box is visible? i've tried many approaches.. none of which work

Comment: no that wnt work because i would have to refresh the page in its current state for it to listen if the item is now visibe.....awkward....

Comment: Let's try another way. Set after document ready: `$('.noclick').on('click', '', function(e) { e.stopPropagation(); });`. And replace code `':not(.noclick)'` in my answer with `''`.

Comment: @dragonvsphoenix, please, put your example on http://jsfiddle.net for all to know exactly what you want.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/1kzanprk/ it works on jsfiddle.... but i have the EXACT same code on my website and i click the noclick zone and it still fades out... what am i missing??

Comment: @dragonvsphoenix, I have fixed bugs in your javascript http://jsfiddle.net/1kzanprk/1/

Comment: yes that does work.... so i have given you the tick.... unfortunately that stops any javascript inside the box (i.e the google sign in button) so im gonna have to try and think of another way round it. thanx for your help tho.@dizel3d

Comment: oh actually i just had to get rid of 'noclick' class from the google button, so all is good. thanx @dizel3d